# How can I check if current user is the admin in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to change a client form if they have paid cash to me(the admin). Hypothetical cash, not real cash. So in order to change the form, I have used something like this:

```
if current_user.user_type == :client
    show normal form 
elsif current_user.user_type == :admin
    show normal form + more functionality
end
```

So what is the best way to implement the "user_type" function? I was thinking about adding that function to the User class like below. The return :seller and return :client works normally. I have tested that. Can I check the email and password of the current user (The current_user is me, with the already made password and email)? This doesn't seem to work. Whats the best way to do it?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client
  has_one :seller

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  acts_as_messageable

     def user_type
         return :client if self.client(&:info_complete?)
         return :seller if self.seller(&:info_complete?)
         return :admin if (self.email == 'admin@gmail.com' && self.password == 'admintestpass')
     end  
end
```

Comment: What I've done in the past is add a column to the users table called `role` or something like that, then make it an enum. Rails enums are nice to use. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html.  The only reason I hesitate to endorse your solution is that if the logic to determine roles becomes more complex, it would make more sense to store the role than compute it every time. If you'd like me to make an answer detailing the steps for the enum solution, let me know

Comment: @0101001101000010 Yes please!! Also, would my way make everything slower? because it'll be computing everytime?

Comment: I think the real penalty will come with maintainability later on, not so much performance. Right now you have a pretty simple way of telling who is admin, but what if that rule changes? What if you create another admin whose email is `me@random.hotmail.net`? You would have to change your rule, and if eventually you have dozens of admins it'll be a nightmare to make a rule governing them all. It's easier to store user roles permanently. I usually create an admin page where admins can change user roles. Also, it's not typically a good idea to check a users password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first you need to create a migration to add a column (I would name it `role`, don't use `type` because it will cause problems later on) to the user table. I'm assuming you know how to write migrations, if not ask for an example in the comments. The column needs to be of type `int`. `null: false, defaul: 0` is a good idea to avoid some user not having roles. Then comes the model:

This is where rails enums save the day. For my example, assume the column is named `role`

```
    model User < ApplicationRecord #boilerplate stuff
      enum role: [ :client, :seller, :admin ] # These are the different possible roles

      def assign_role
        if # logic to decide role here
          self.update_attribute(:role, :admin) # This makes the user admin
        else
          self.update_attribute(:role, :client) # This makes the user client
        end
      end
    end
```

Note: the assign role method isn't required for enums to work, I just added it so you could see how to assign the roles and save them to users.

Then in your controller (or view if you want) you can check if a user is admin by:
`user.admin? # true if admin, false otherwise`

You can do the same for all roles (check documentation provided for a fuller explanation):
`user.client? # true if client, false otherwise`
`user.seller? # true if seller, false otherwise`

Last thing to keep in mind, if your column has a `default: 0`, the first item in the `enum` list will be the default role, in this case it's `client`. You'll want to keep this in mind when creating new users.

And finally, documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html